# Good solution for virtualized chat view in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have to develop a new chat interface for our web app. I tried using `vue-virtual-scroller` to virtualize the list of messages and attachments but I have some issues regarding updating the list and scrolling to the bottom.

Did anyone ever had to do the same via this package and had success with scrolling programmatically while also adding new items at the end of the list?

Hope someone can help me with this! Would like to push something to production today! :)

Comment: Short addition: The biggest issue occurs when I push a new item to the virtual list and then try to scroll to the bottom. The list starts to jump around and scrolls into the center of the whole scroll container.

Comment: Could you provide some code, please? [mcve]

Comment: @Jns thanks. I created a simple code sandbox. It's far away from a chat but should be enough: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn121l1n83

You can add new items and I added a small timeout to wait until I scroll programmatically. You can see how the virtualized scroll list jumps around when data changes. I believe this is what causes my chat to go crazy.